# Understanding the 'detection_boxes' in output dictionary when running inference on an image (object detection)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Here is a code snippet taken from a [Tensorflow tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/) for putting an image through a model and getting an output dictionary containing the results of the model inference.

```
    # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
    # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis,...]

    # Run inference
    model_fn = self.model.signatures['serving_default']
    output_dict = model_fn(input_tensor)

    # All outputs are batches tensors.
    # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
    # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
    num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
    output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                    for key,value in output_dict.items()}
    output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    # Handle models with masks:
    if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        # Reframe the the bbox mask to the image size.
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
                  output_dict['detection_masks'], output_dict['detection_boxes'],
                   image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(detection_masks_reframed > 0.5,
                                           tf.uint8)
        output_dict['detection_masks_reframed'] = detection_masks_reframed.numpy()
    return output_dict
```

I have been printing out output_dict and have been trying to understand all the information it outputs. When I looked into 'detection_boxes', I would out that it contains the max and min of the x and y values of its respective bounding box. However, I noticed that their values were always very small decimal numbers. I'm not entirely sure as to why this is the case and was hoping someone here could help me in understanding this. Any input on the matter is appreciated.